# Error when sending Email using Power shell

Tags: powershell

I have plain email script. It works on my W10 PC but not on any 2012 server: Here is my code:

```
$SMTP = "smtp.office365.com"
$From = "myemail.net"
$To = "companyemail.com"
$Subject = "Test Subject"
$Body = "This is a test message"
$Email = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTP, 587)
$Email.EnableSsl = $true
$Email.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail.net", "*****");
$Email.Send($From, $To, $Subject, $Body)
```

when running the script a server 2012 I get the following error:

Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "Failure sending mail." At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\GAtest.ps1:9 char:1

$Email.Send($From, $To, $Subject, $Body)

- CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

Again it works perfectly on a W10 PC Please help Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enabled `-Verbose` or `-Debug` to see if there are any additional warning messages?

My first thought for Server 2012 is that TLS 1.2 might not be enabled. Try setting this first in your script:

`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Comment: Yes that did it

Comment: Happy to help! If you wouldn't mind, could you mark this as the answer?